# How to calculate P(A∩B), P(A∩C), P(B∩C) and P(A∪C), P(B∪C)?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

A particular computer program outputs a number in {0,2,3} with probabilities as follows:

$0 $ has a probability of $\frac{1}{3}$

$2$ has a probability of $\frac{1}{2}$

$3$ has a probability of $\frac{1}{6}$

The program is run twice and its first and second output are recorded.

Let A be the event that the  first output is $0$.

Let B be the event that the second output is $2$.

Let C be the event that the sum of the two outputs is exactly $5$.

- **(a)** Find $P(A)$, $P(B)$ and $P(C)$.
- **(b)** Find $P(A∩B)$, $P(A∩C)$ and $P(B∩C)$.
- **(c)** Are $A$ and $C$ independent events? Are $B$ and $C$ independent events?
- **(d)** Find $P(A∪C)$ and $P(B∪C)$.

This is how I attempted this:

For **part a)** $P(A) = \frac{1}{3}$, $P(B) = \frac{1}{2}$, $P(C) = (2,3) or (3,2) = \frac{1}{6}$

For **part b)** **This is where I have a problem I am not sure how to find $P(A∩B)$, $P(A∩C)$ and $P(B∩C)$.**

For part c) A and C independent only if P(A∩C) = P(A)P(C)

For **part d)** **This is also where I have a problem**, if I knew the answers to the part b I would be able to find this.

Comment: Hint: Are the outputs independent?  If you know the answer for the first output, does it affect the second output?

Comment: For b), c) and d) you need to think about what the different events _mean_. For instance, $A\cap C$ means that the first output is $0$, and at the same time, the two outputs sum to $5$. How possible does that sound? What does that make $P(A\cap C)$?

Comment: Yea they are independent

Comment: A∩C does not make sense in that case. So is A∩C=0 in that case because an event cannot be both A and C at the same time?

Comment: so is B being 1/2 correct?

Answer (score 2):

$(b)$

The runs of the program are independent.

$$P(A \cap B) = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2}$$

$C$ can not occur with $A$ because $A$ has the value $0$.

$$P(A \cap C) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 0$$

For $B$ and $C$ to occur we must have a $3$ on the first run.

$$P(B \cap C) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{6} $$

$(c)$

You have the probabilities of the intersection of the events
and the individual events, check if

$P(U \cap V) = P(U)P(V)$

for $A$ and $C$, $B$ and $C$.

$(d)$

Use the formula

$P(U \cup V) = P(U) + P(V) - P(U \cap V)$

for $A$ and $C$, $B$ and $C$. You have already calculated what you need.